# How do the AMOUNT_SPREAD parameters for the kelp balanced strategy result in profit?

Tags: kelp

In the balanced configuration file the following explanation for `MIN_AMOUNT_SPREAD` and `MAX_AMOUNT_SPREAD` appears:

> reduces the order size by this percentage (specified as a decimal number). if someone buys and sells the full order amount placed you
>   will end up with a profit equaling this percentage multiplied by the
>   full order amount, effectively making this a spread.

followed by the example values:

```
MIN_AMOUNT_SPREAD = 0.0005
MAX_AMOUNT_SPREAD = 0.0005
```

I'm not following why reducing the amount of a level order results in profit; how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balanced strategy estimates a price for the two tokens relative to each other; that's the **centerPrice**. Anytime you place an order to sell with a spread, you are effectively selling at a **better** price (in the bot's favor) than what is estimated. Conversely, if you buy with a spread you are buying at a **better** price (in the bot's favor) than what is estimated.

However, when someone *buys* or *sells* to you it is an indicator of the market's relative demand for the two assets. Therefore, the act of having your order get converted to a trade *reveals* information by the market. The bot *incorporates* this new information by using the *asset balances* to estimate a new **centerPrice**.

**The bot knows the maximum amount it can support to buy/sell** w.r.t. it's *knowledge of the current market demand*. It does this by **predicting the effect of a trade on the future centerPrice** and factors that in to the maximum amount it can support. This is the amount at which if the market traded with the bot on both sides (*buy followed by sell or sell followed by buy*) then the bot would end up with a net 0 token gain (not accounting for negligible fees on the Stellar network).

Any amount lower than the *maximum amount* will result in a gain by the bot if the market were to both buy and sell. This gain comes from the `SPREAD` and the `AMOUNT_SPREAD` which allows you to define smaller amounts to trade compared to the maximum amount supported at each spread level. **If the market were to consume a full order level placed by the bot then the bot has on average bought or sold at a price that is *better* by a percentage equal to `AMOUNT_SPREAD` compared to it's estimate of the *centerPrice* (in the bot's favor)**.

Comment: Thanks. How do MIN_AMOUNT_SPREAD and MAX_AMOUNT_SPREAD interact? Specifically, what is the difference between those values being identical vs. them being different, i.e. MIN and 0.0005 and MAX at 0.0007?

Comment: The bot picks a random value between min and max. so if min and max are the same then there is no randomness. The randomness makes your market look less jagged.